# Use some tags and variables from other template to a different

Tags: python, django, tags, django-templates, django-views

I have designed a list of categories (actually i have only two categories created) from this model:

```
class SuperCategory(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'library', null=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(SuperCategory, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I can list all categories in my template normaly:

```
class SuperCatView(ListView):

    template = 'products/supercategory_list.html'
    model = SuperCategory
```

**supercategory_list.html:**

```
{% for supercategory in object_list %}
            <li>
                <img src="{{ supercategory.image.url }}" alt="" />
                <div class="portfolio-item-content">
                    <span class="header">{{ supercategory.name }}</span>
                    <p class="body">{{ supercategory.description }}</p>
                </div>
                <a href="{% url 'products:vista_categories' pk=supercategory.pk %}"><i class="more">+</i></a>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
```

My problem is, I wanna list the same categories in a second template located in the same directory called **"sample.html"**, I thought on first instance only put the same tags used in the first template to "sample.html":

```
{% for supercategory in object_list %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">{{ supercategory.name }}</a>
                        </li>
                        {% endfor %}
```

but nothing is shown. what should I change to list my categories in both templates?.

I'm new in django and also in python, apologizeme in advance if I overlook something.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you created a second view to use with `sample.html` template?

```
class SampleCatView(SuperCatView):
    template = 'products/sample.html'
```

You can inherit your first view and just override the template :-)